# do while loop condition in c

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements, pic

Does the two code snipets below do exactly the same thing?

```
do
{
    Delay_us(1);
    status = fetchStatus();
}while(!status);
```

Second snipet ->

```
do
{
    Delay_us(1);
}while(status = fetchStatus(), !status);
```

which is preferable?

Comment: That second one is horrid. The alternative to the first is realistically `while (!(status = fetchStatus())`.

Comment: Is the second one even legal? Doesn't the condition of a loop need to be a valid expression? What would that even evalulate to?

Comment: @prelic: It's (to my knowledge) an obscure feature that causes confusion when used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @DanFego wow...if I had to work with that code, I'd be seriously annoyed.

Comment: @prelic: It's valid.  A comma-separated expression evaluates in left-to-right order and has the value of the rightmost expression.

Comment: @DrewDormann gotcha...still would much rather see the first option.  But I guess that just means I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: They are equivalent. However, I am wondering what happens if above code is in critical section in a multi-threaded process? I don't know if the boolean expression inside the while braces is executed atomically. If it is then, I think answer @Richard J. Ross III seems appropriate as it seems like a reentrant code.

Comment: @BhaskarUpadhyayula: They are equivalent in every way, even in the presence of multiple threads and reentrancy; the comma operator introduces a sequence point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do the same, but I would prefer the following:

```
do {
    Delay_us(1);
} while (!(status = fetchStatus()));
```

As it streamlines it all together into one statement, not two.

Comment: Huh?  This doesn't reduce the number of calls.

Comment: @StephenCanon excuse me, it reduces the number of statements, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
do
{
    Delay_us(1);
} while( !fetchStatus() );
```

That way you do not need to create a local variable if you **do not** use it.

Comment: How do you know that he don't use it?

Comment: @asaelr I do not know that the OP doesn't use it, I am just gleaning from the OP.

Comment: @Christian then I would suggest using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8932005/561731), it might be more suited to what you need.

Comment: @Neal +1 because I like that answer you linked :)

Comment: @Christian no problem, thats what we are here for, to help!

Answer (score 1):

They have the same logical output.  In each case status is assigned and then evaluated, but the first is much more readable.  In general dont use the comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent.  Since they're equivalent, neither is preferred.  Some people may like the first more aesthetically because it's more familiar, however.

Do you really intend to delay before the first check of status?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but I believe we're getting into the realm of compiler optimization.  It really depend on which compiler you use to generate the binary from that code.  One compiler may take code like your first snippet and optimize it into binary code that effectively does what your second snippet does.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(; !fetchStatus(); Delay_us(1));
```